# How to create a linked list in pure C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to know how to create a single linked list in C where each node has:

- A string of any length.
- A list of integers (the total number of integers to store will vary between nodes, so I cant use an array of integers).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You honestly can't find an example of this with Google? I see...

Comment: And on the 8th day.. He created [Google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: I know how to create the single linked list, where each node has  'strings' of any length. But I dont know how to implement the numerical list inside each node of the external list.

Comment: OK so just make another linked list for each list of numbers?

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Post code with the 1) external list (with strings), 2) the numerical list, 3) and the way you tried to combine these two.

Comment: If you already know how to do it with strings, numbers are exactly the same except the type will be `int*` or `double*` instead of `char*`. You still have to allocate the array just like you would the string, and you access it the same way (except that you don't have convenience functions like `strcpy()`).

Comment: Will you know how many integers are in the list of integers when you create a node in the outer list, or can that inner list change after the node is created?  If it is 'fixed once created', the inner list can be be handled by a dynamically allocated array; if not, you need a 'list of `int`' type as well as your 'list of node-containing-string-and-list-of-`int`' type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but here are some steps to get you started. This is one possible way of doing it; there are others that might work better given your actual needs.

First, determine your data structures. You need two. The first is the linked list of integers. The second is the linked list that contains both the string and the list. Here is what the nodes in the latter might look like:

```
typedef struct node {
    char* someStr;
    LIST* integerList;
    struct node* next;
} NODE;
```

Then, have one function that creates the linked list of integers. Have another function that allocates memory for the string and returns a `char*`.

Have a third function that takes as parameters the linked list of `NODE`s, a string, and a linked list of `int`s. This function appends a new `NODE` to the list, setting the pointers to the linked list of `int` and the string.

At least get started with this. If you get stuck on any of the functions, you can ask specific questions about them. But you cannot just post the problem and expect someone to write the code for you, without saying what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: +1 For "I'm not going to write the code for you". Programming is learned by doing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from:

> A list of integers (the total number of integers to store will vary between nodes, so I cant use an array of integers).

It seems that you want a dynamic array for numbers, you can use [This CCAN Module](https://github.com/rustyrussell/ccan/blob/master/ccan/darray/darray.h) (It's just a header, just remove the config.h inclusion and you should be good to go)

**NB**: a List of numbers seems like a bad idea, so dynamic array is probably the most effecient way of doing this.

**NB2**: It's not hard to code your own dynamic array, just have a look at [it's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

Simplest usage is something like:

```
#include "darray.h"

struct node {
    char *string;
    darray(int) numbers;
};

inline void push_number(struct node *node, int number) {
    darray_push(node->numbers, number);
}
```

Comment: I think he meant no third party libraries with "pure C".

Comment: @Kunal That's why I wrote the 2nd NB.